# React Native Android: using new debug.keystore in project

Tags: google-play, react-native, google-play-services

I'm trying to submit a build of my React Native project to the Google Play store, and realized I had the wrong `debug.keystore` file in my `HOME/.android` folder. I found the correct `debug.keystore` file elsewhere, and replaced the one in `HOME/.android` with it. I now get the error `Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "HOME/.android/debug.keystore": keystore password was incorrect`

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the debug.keystore from react native [github project](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/template/android/app/debug.keystore)
also the password configuration for this keystore for react-native projects is normally declared in `signingConfigs` there you will find the **keystore password** make sure it is the correct one, but still you should not use a **debug keystore** to submit an app to google Play store I believe it would be rejected for this the recomendation is to create a release keystore and add the corresponding configuration to the `signingConfigs` you can check detailed explanation of the proccess in [react native docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)